# Difference between putting shaders in "Always Included Shaders" vs "Preloaded Assets"

Tags: unity, shaders, optimization, assets, build-process

I am developing an mobile AR application with Unity AR Foundation. After a successful android build, I was told one of the shaders was not found.

> ShaderNotFoundException: GLTF/PbrMetallicRoughness not found. Did you forget to add it to the build?

I realized I forgot to include one of the shaders that is only loaded at runtime.

I searched the internet and was taught to include the shader under **Project Settings -> Graphics -> Always Included Shaders**. That totally made sense but I was faced with the same problem everybody faced, the building takes ages as it compiles all my shader variants.

I stopped the build and opted for a method that was not mentioned by the internet, I went to **Project Settings -> Player -> Optimization** and included the shader under **Preloaded Assets**. The build was much faster and the shader was loaded correctly in my application.

At this point, my build error is solved but I can't help wondering if it is correct to do so. I am not seeing anyone mentioning about this method and there is not official documentation recommending including shaders under **Preloaded Assets**.

Could anybody help me out by explaining (hopefully) what these 2 methods actually do to my build, and what is considered the best practice to include the shaders?

I am using Unity 2020.3